# Adding a .pem certificate to flask (dev server)

Tags: python, flask, https, ssl-certificate

I have a developed a flask app (i am rookie in flask dev). I have hosted on my test server, now the requirement is to establish a secured https connection . I have a .pem file from my organizations's CA. I am not able to use it in my flask app. Most solutions i find on the net are with cert and key file. I just have a pem file, how do i go about it? I am new to certificates. The code i am using is something like this:

> if **name** == '**main**':
> context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
>
> context = ('/apps/axiom_app/flask/cert_root.pem','/apps/axiom_app/flask/cert.org.com.cer')
>
> app.secret_key = os.urandom(12)
> app.run(ssl_context=context, host=so.gethostbyname(so.gethostname()), >port=v_port, debug=True, use_reloader=True)

AND the error i get is:

context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3837)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For every situation where an SSL connection is required the **development** server is not sufficient. Please use one of the options from https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/ !

Comment: Thanks Klaus, do you mean i need to host Flask  on GUNICORN or any stand alone wsgi containers?

Comment: Yes, the development server is for development only (a developer acceccing it, mostly on the same machine). Every other user should come through a production grade WSGI implementation.